# Executing dynamic Java code over JSR-223

Tags: java, jsr223

I have been executing dynamic code in my application over JSR-223 for a while now. The basics logic is:

```
ScriptEngineManager scriptEngineManager = new ScriptEngineManager();
ScriptEngine scriptEngine = scriptEngineManager.getEngineByName(engineName);
final CompiledScript compiled = ((Compilable) scriptEngine).compile(script);
Bindings bindings = scriptEngine.getBindings(ScriptContext.ENGINE_SCOPE);
bindings.put("key", value);
compiled.eval(bindings);
```

This works great for Nashorn and Groovy scripting engines. However it would be great if extending the logic of the application would not require knowing the syntax and tricks of another language - the base code is in Java after all.

When listing the built-in engines there do not seem to be any present for Java:

```
ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
List<ScriptEngineFactory> factoryList = manager.getEngineFactories();
for (ScriptEngineFactory factory : factoryList) {
    log.debug(factory.getLanguageName());
}
```

I have found a few dynamic Java libraries but they do not seem to be maintained any more. I guess it is possible to write something together using the `javax.tools.JavaCompiler` but I am hoping that maybe I am missing something basic and there are working options for such a thing already in existence. I am also aware of the basics about jshell coming in Java 9 but I have not heard anything about it allowing code execution using the ScriptEngineManager.

How should I go about implementing scripting using the Java language itself? Are there any options beyond starting to implement my own `javax.script.ScriptEngine` with the help of `javax.tools.JavaCompiler`?

Comment: So you want a java scripting engine that runs in the jvm? Does not sound terribly efficient.  To generate dynamic code from text JavaCompiler does the trick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am a bit late for this thread, but I just released version 1.1.0 of the jshell-scriptengine.

Have at look at:
https://github.com/eobermuhlner/jshell-scriptengine

Comment: Thanks, this looks like the best answer so far. I have mostly used the Groovy engine over the JSR223 interface so far as the syntax is almost the same - most Java code runs just fine. I wonder if you have made any performance comparisons between different JSR223 implementations and jshell-scriptengine? How does your library stack up to the others?

Comment: I haven't done any serious benchmarking yet, but the JShell is definitely on the slow side since it needs to recompile the script snippets every time.

Comment: I am currently working on a script engine based on the `javax.tools.JavaCompiler` and dynamic class loading but it isn't production ready yet (give me a few more days).
https://github.com/eobermuhlner/java-scriptengine

Comment: The https://github.com/eobermuhlner/java-scriptengine has just been released version 1.0.0

Comment: Cool, thanks for linking. What is the best way to reach out in case people have some questions? Issue tracker in Github? For example I am not clear on the difference between the two implementations. I realize one runs using the JShell but it is still possible to reuse the compiled scripts there and not recompile the code on every execution (by your examples)... So is it still significantly slower than the java-scriptengine? What benefits does the second library bring? I assume the JShell-scriptengine can also load classes dynamically from the executing JVM?

Comment: For communication you can either use the gitter chat https://gitter.im/java-scriptengine/community on the java-scriptengine github page or create github issues if you find bugs.
The quick answer is that JShell is slower because it needs to compile the script snippets for every evaluation. The java-scriptengine is faster because the Java code is compiled only once and the evaluation are a simple method call into the compiled class.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [SciJava Java Scripting plugin](https://github.com/scijava/scripting-java)

Docs are a bit thin. See the [Maven Repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.scijava/scripting-java/0.4.1) and note that the resolver is the ImageJ Releases repository (http://maven.imagej.net/content/repositories/releases/)

Comment: Thanks, this is the closest thing I have seen so far. I have not had the time to check it out in detail yet but at least it looks pretty promising as long as it does what it promises to do. 

I see you have already submitted an issue in their repository so you must have been testing it yourself as well. It would be great if you could add more details about your experience

Comment: My issue links to unit tests that show the problems I have found with each JSR223 implementation. The gold standard is Nashorn, with Jython running a close second. All the others have issues which seem like they should be relatively easy to address, however those issues prevent my usage.

Comment: Please don't just post some tool or library as an answer. At least demonstrate [how it solves the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605) in the answer itself.

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen [JShell tool](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~rfield/tutorial/JShellTutorial.html) and [API](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/jdk.jshell-summary.html) in #java9? It is not JSR-223 based - nevertheless a Java API (and a command line tool) that uses Java as a "scripting language".

Comment: Yes, I have seen it. I am looking for a solution specifically working with JSR-223 because other languages are already used over that interface and I want to avoid creating a multitude of interfaces to maintain. Thank you for the suggestion though