# External dataloading at runtime

Tags: java, file, parsing, load, runtime

I have a file that contain some variables and vectors (in Java format) and would like to load it at runtime and have those variables accessible from the program. It feels unnecessary having to parse it. This isn't a class file, think of it as a txt file with:

```
    int a = 5;
    int[] b= [1,2,3];
```

Comment: You can read the text file in the Java program and use the contents as needed. You can consider using a properties file. Can you post some sample data from the txt file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can execute any java code using [JSR223](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45037984/executing-dynamic-java-code-over-jsr-223) scripting, just load the file to `script`:

> ```
> ScriptEngineManager scriptEngineManager = new ScriptEngineManager();
> ScriptEngine scriptEngine = scriptEngineManager.getEngineByName(engineName);
> final CompiledScript compiled = ((Compilable) scriptEngine).compile(script);
> Bindings bindings = scriptEngine.getBindings(ScriptContext.ENGINE_SCOPE);
> bindings.put("key", value);
> compiled.eval(bindings);
> ```